# How to measure disk drive bandwidth using while transferring files in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

How can disk read/write speeds be measured in Windows during normal operation of the system?

For example, if I'm transferring files via `robocopy` I'd like to ascertain the overall bus saturation for I/O during an operation for performance tuning (ie, adjusting the number of transfer threads, `/MT:X`).

Comment: Depends on what you actually want to see. Task Manager reports business and throughput for each drive.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB that's sufficient. Not quite as robust as other options I've seen on other operating systems, but this will work. 

Answer (score 1):

1. Manually create a large batch of files, small, medium large size, and [measure how long it takes to transfer](https://www.howtogeek.com/227198/how-to-test-your-network-or-hard-drive-speeds-with-a-dummy-file-in-windows/) as you change parameters.
2. Use any of the available [tools that measure transfer rate](https://thegeekpage.com/best-free-tools-to-measure-hard-drive-performance-of-windows-10/), and see how close Robocopy is to the maxima they determine. You can see what tweaks improve the rate... or if they're needed at all.